# jquery load/unload content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing my first project with jquery:

My site will have some tabs: 
1. I've got a list which will be the tabbar.
2. I've got a lot of content-container-divs which I hide() / show() depending on which tab I clicked.

My question/s: 
Should I load() unload these divs, even if they are in the same html ?
(on jquery-docs they load from external html-files)
Could I / should I combine my existing method(hiding and showing the divs) with loading/unloading them?
-> something like unloading all the tabs which are not visible...
What would be a good approach, If I know there will be quite a lot of content ?
How could a minimal example look like ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: im commenting because i dont think my answer qualifies as a good answer, if its static, load it all at once, and hide show, internet speeds are much better nowadays they can handle up to 500 KB with good speed, ajaxing is for functionality not content, because u lose the back button with it. u also dont want the user to keep loading EVERY time... if ur concerned, be smart about when and how much to load, some websites load only when content "comes into view", meaning when users scroll down to see, others load images when they "come into view", third load when requested just once...

Comment: I think that's a pretty good answer Ayyash, I was going to suggest the same. Load smart, you're trying to minimize ajax calls as well as initial page size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), why should you code something that has already been coded?